# Como recuparar o novo nome de um arquivo em um upload "Drag and Drop" automatico

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, file-upload

Encontrei um sistema de `upload` de imagens **`Drag and Drop`** na internet que faz o `upload` da imagem em uma pasta especifica e renomeia o arquivo com um nome aleatório sem precisar enviar o formulário.

Porem não consigo recuperar o novo nome do arquivo para gravar no banco de dados?

[Link do projeto](https://github.com/CreativeDream/php-uploader)

https://github.com/CreativeDream/php-uploader

Simplifiquei o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="html">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Example 1 - jQuery Filer 1.3 - CreativeDream</title>

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="../../css/jquery.filer.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../../css/themes/jquery.filer-dragdropbox-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Jvascript -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="../../js/jquery.filer.min.js" type="text/javascript">      </script>
    <script src="./js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div>

    <form name="form" action="" method="post">

        <div id="content">

            <!-- Example 2 -->
            <input type="file" name="files[]" id="filer_input2" multiple="multiple">
            <!-- end of Example 2 -->

            <input class="button" type="submit" name="publicar" value="Publicar"/>

        </div>
    </form>

    </div>
</body>
```

```
if( isset( $_POST['publicar'] ) ) {
    $img = $_POST['files']
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/CreativeDream/php-uploader/blob/master/src/class.uploader.php olha o código pronto ai!!!! igual está no exemplo! entendeu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você enviar vários arquivos ou apenas um existe um `array` que informa os nomes gerados que possui a *`chave`* `name`:

***Local especifico no código exemplo:***

```
if($data['isComplete']){
    $files = $data['data'];
    foreach($files['metas'] as $values)
    {
        //aqui são os nomes gerados  
        echo $values['name'];
    }
}
```

ou seja, `$values['name']` utilize para gravar na sua base de dados.

---

Além do nome do arquivo gerado possui diversas informações:

```
Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [0] => uploads/Lh3EGOrl7D.jpg
            [1] => uploads/nJVhvxBXQD.jpg
            [2] => uploads/0kJOf_ABQt.jpg
            [3] => uploads/lH9ZrpGAbM.jpg
        )

    [metas] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => Thu, 06 Oct 2016 17:15:00 -0300
                    [extension] => jpg
                    [file] => uploads/Lh3EGOrl7D.jpg
                    [name] => Lh3EGOrl7D.jpg
                    [old_name] => 14064104_10209380587605927_5793335061447087469_n.jpg
                    [replaced] => 
                    [size] => 8251
                    [size2] => 8.06 KB
                    [type] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => image
                            [1] => jpeg
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [date] => Thu, 06 Oct 2016 17:15:00 -0300
                    [extension] => jpg
                    [file] => uploads/nJVhvxBXQD.jpg
                    [name] => nJVhvxBXQD.jpg
                    [old_name] => 14192672_1402374739778600_7123746786432954771_n.jpg
                    [replaced] => 
                    [size] => 14404
                    [size2] => 14.07 KB
                    [type] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => image
                            [1] => jpeg
                        )

                )
```

como extensão, antigo nome de arquivo, tamanho, data de envio, etc. Esses valores em chave pode ser utilizado no `foreach` se assim quiser.

---

***Código Completo:***

**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Laravel</title>
    <link href="css/jquery.filer.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/themes/jquery.filer-dragdropbox-theme.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.filer.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
    <div class="content">
        <form action="upSave.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="files[]" id="filer_input" multiple="multiple">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#filer_input').filer();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

    require_once("class.uploader.php");

    $uploader = new Uploader();
    $data = $uploader->upload($_FILES['files'], array(
        'limit' => 10, //Maximum Limit of files. {null, Number}
        'maxSize' => 10, //Maximum Size of files {null, Number(in MB's)}
        'extensions' => null, //Whitelist for file extension. {null, Array(ex: array('jpg', 'png'))}
        'required' => false, //Minimum one file is required for upload {Boolean}
        'uploadDir' => 'uploads/', //Upload directory {String}
        'title' => array('auto', 10), //New file name {null, String, Array} *please read documentation in README.md
        'removeFiles' => true, //Enable file exclusion {Boolean(extra for jQuery.filer), String($_POST field name containing json data with file names)}
        'replace' => false, //Replace the file if it already exists {Boolean}
        'perms' => null, //Uploaded file permisions {null, Number}
        'onCheck' => null, //A callback function name to be called by checking a file for errors (must return an array) | ($file) | Callback
        'onError' => null, //A callback function name to be called if an error occured (must return an array) | ($errors, $file) | Callback
        'onSuccess' => null, //A callback function name to be called if all files were successfully uploaded | ($files, $metas) | Callback
        'onUpload' => null, //A callback function name to be called if all files were successfully uploaded (must return an array) | ($file) | Callback
        'onComplete' => null, //A callback function name to be called when upload is complete | ($file) | Callback
        'onRemove' => 'onFilesRemoveCallback' //A callback function name to be called by removing files (must return an array) | ($removed_files) | Callback
    ));

    if($data['isComplete']){
        $files = $data['data'];
        //print_r($files);
        foreach($files['metas'] as $values)
        {
            echo $values['name'];
            echo '<br />';
        }
    }

    if($data['hasErrors']){
        $errors = $data['errors'];
        print_r($errors);
    }
```

Comment: Não consigo recuperar o array com o nome

Comment: @DanilloEder coloque na sua pergunta o código html e o código do upload por favor!

Comment: Adicionei, o restante não muda nada.

Comment: @DanilloEder esse pacote de `Drag and Drop` tem um classe pronta pra upload (https://github.com/CreativeDream/php-uploader/blob/master/src/class.uploader.php) que facilita isso com códigos de exemplo, eu postei o html e o código pronto com um `require_once("class.uploader.php");` e o resto do código, vai facilitar sua codificação.

Comment: :D Funcionou, obrigado!